# At how small does the uncertainty in position have to become to create uncertainty in momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

At what range of possible positions (i.e. what diameter opening) is the uncertainty principle invoked (i.e. where more uncertainty is created in the momentum space)? How small of a range of momentums does a superposition have to become to create uncertainty in momentum? By extension, what are the units used in the uncertainty principle equation,

$$\Delta x \Delta p \geq \frac{h}{4\pi}$$

Comment: The uncertainty principle is exactly the answer to your question. What are you asking?

Comment: It has units of action, so is measured in Js.

Answer (score 0):

Heisenberg's uncertainty principle is **always** applicable. However, due to $h\over 4{\pi}$ being such a small quantity, it does not have much effect on large objects.

For example, a ball of mass $1\;\text{kg}$ moving at $10\;\text{m}/ \text{s}$, the variation in position is given as 
$${\Delta x}\;{\ge}\;5.27\times 10^{-36}\text{m}$$

This length is smaller than the Planck length and such a variation has absolutely no meaning in physics. Hence the principle is usually only applied on objects with tiny masses as the variation becomes appreciable.